# Office Add-in: data stored in localStorage not available from Dialog in Excel desktop Office365

Tags: local-storage, office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently working on an Excel Add-in which is being developed using the Office JS API. I have a command which opens a dialog (using the Office Dialog API) in which I have an SPA (built with Vue.js). The app we are targeting is Excel on desktop, Office365.

The problem that I am having is that the data that I store in window.localStorage is not accessible from my dialog. For example, before opening the dialog, in the host window (the UI-less function file of my add-in command) I do window.localStorage.setItem("item1", "Hello World") and then inside my dialog I try to read that via window.localStorage.getItem("item1"), but the data is not there.

Using Microsoft Edge Dev tools (Microsoft Edge 94) from the parent I am able to see the value in the local storage, so it is correctly set. But if I do the same thing from my dialog, local storage is empty. Tried something similar with cookies, but I'm running into the same problem. Must mention that the dialog has the same domain as the add-in itself.

Shouldn't parent (host window) and child (dialog box) share the same localStorage?

Comment: For those following this question, there's a related GitHub issue with some more information and suggestions: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2140

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior lies in the fact, that two separate JS runtimes are being used, so no shared context exists between your dialog and the main page.

You can find further infos for passing data to dialogs here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#pass-information-to-the-dialog-box
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/parent-to-dialog